# cell value based on multiple cells data

Tags: vba, formulas

I am trying to came up with some formula or code to solve an issue that I have while working with some data for sales orders where I may or may not have inventory

```
Name:  order test.JPG
Views: 4
Size:  98.0 KB
```

On Column F, I need a value based on column A and Column E, for example from rows A15 to A19, based also on the values of E15 to E19, this order is complete and I can print it, SO I expected have a value on column F that tells me this order is good to print, any ideas??

[image]

Comment: Don't attach images to questions for sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In F2 put:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,E:E,"OK to print")=COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"Complete","Partial")
```

And copy down.